# Как напрямую читать файлы .dtl в DataFrame?

Tags: python, dataframe, импорт

Анализирую логи, которые АСУТП сохраняет в файлы *.dtl. Чтобы импортировать их в DataFrame, сначала перевожу их в .xlsx с помощью утилиты производителя (Easy Builder).

Проблема в том, что у меня этих файлов тысячи, а конвертер за один раз больше 15 штук не принимает.

Есть ли какие-нибудь способы напрямую читать файлы .dtl?

Файл для примера прилагаю: [download .dtl (31 kb)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h2L5i0oLXXtm3ZpAqWig2d0pLFEaB9tg/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: доступ к файлу откройте, чтоли

Comment: @strawdog, прошу прощения, поправил.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по [документации](https://dl.weintek.com/public/EBPro/UserManual/eng/EasyBuilderPro_V60501_UserManual_eng.pdf) утилита для конвертирования может работать из командной строки:

```
EasyConverter.exe /t1 /s "C:\Format.lgs" "C:\Src.dtl" "C:\Dest.xls"
```

> **Parameter Description**
>
> `/c{a,8,u}` Optional, specifies encoding method, only required when
> exporting a .csv file.
>
> `/ca` : ASCII (Default)
>
> `/c8` : UTF-8 `/cu` :
>
> Unicode `/t{0,1}` Optional, specifies whether or not to include
> millisecond information.

> EasyConverter EasyBuilder Pro V6.05.01
>
> `/t0` : Excludes millisecond information.
>
> `/t1` : Includes millisecond information. (Default)
>
> `/s` Optional, specifies whether or not to import settings file. To
> import settings file, specify the path of .lgs file following `/s`.
> For example: `/s "C:\Format.lgs"`
>
> "Src file" Specifies the source file path, and the file format should
> be: .dtl, .evt, or .db
>
> "Dest file" Specifies the destination file path, and the file format
> can be: .xls or .csv. See Note.

Поэтому можно легко сгенерировать `.BAT` / `.CMD` файл, в котором данная утилита вызывается для каждого `.dtl` файла.